# Return strings which contains number on specific position

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am basic on SQL queries and I need some help.
I have to select all string values which contains number e.g. 7 only on specific position in that string.

For example:
I have string: *987654321* and if on position *3* I will have number *7*, then it should be selected.
So in example this string will be selected, because on 3rd position I have number 7.

Is there any SQL function for that, or something which could help me?

EDIT:

#### Example table

```
      TABLE
Numbers      Value
987654321    1
123456789    2
789009871    3
654321092    4
847949372    5
```

#### Output:

```
       TABLE
Numbers      Value
987654321    1
847949372    5
```

#### Statement:

```
SELECT table.numbers
FROM TABLE
WHERE substr(table.numbers,3,1)='7' <--- what to do here? --->
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `where substr(stringcol, 3, 1) = '7'` to find the 7. Use replace to verify only one 7.

Comment: Please show sample data and a query (leaving out the part you need help figuring out) and the results you expect for the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regex option, you may use MySQL's `REGEXP` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE num REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}7';
```

On Oracle, you could use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(num, '^[0-9]{2}7');
```

Comment: This is shooting sparrows with cannons

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff No, not at all.  Regex is a good choice here assuming we want to match a certain pattern based on position.

Comment: maybe stupid question, but what is *num* in your statement, do not know how I could replace it in my example.

Comment: In your example, `num` would be the name of the column which contains the value e.g. `987654321` which you are trying validate.

Comment: unfortunately REGEX expression does not work for me.. there is 0 output.

Comment: @Frihu My code is working [in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5243f0412be3bdaefcf4b49c7f75088a) please check.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know why it does not work me. I found out that my DB is done in Oracle, not mysql.

Comment: Use `REGEXP_LIKE` on Oracle, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, needed to adjust little bit expression to: `'^.{2}[7]'`. This works for me, with yours I had some problems. Anyway many thanks, I solved my problem with your help.

Comment: @Frihu Strange, because my second Oracle answer is [also working in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a65c2c41deba0af62050d78c267937eb).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You never think about performance or? A substring is a few lines of code to process, a regex is a bunch of code.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I generally agree with you, but in either case, an index can't be used in the `WHERE` clause because we need some function.  Should the OP's logic get a bit more complex than this, it would be sitting more comfortably with regex than the base string operations, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should use case statement.

```
select case when substr(stringcol, 3,1) = '7' then stringcol else "not valid" end as stringcol from <Table Name>
```

Comment: will it complicate, if I will mention that type of these columns are CHAR?